# GStreamer Pipeline Delay Issue with Multiple rtspclientsink Outputs

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I am working on a GStreamer pipeline that involves two rtspclientsink outputs. Here is the pipeline I am using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=10/1,format=I420,colorimetry=bt601 ! queue ! v4l2h264enc ! tee name=t ! queue ! rtspclientsink name=s location=rtsp://localhost:8554/realtime t. ! queue min-threshold-time=4000000000 max-size-time=100000000000 ! rtspclientsink name=b location=rtsp://localhost:8554/delayed
```

My goal is to have the `rtspclientsink rtsp://localhost:8554/realtime` output play in real-time, and the `rtsp://localhost:8554/delayed` output play with a 4-second delay. However, I am experiencing an issue where both outputs are delayed and I am not achieving real-time playback with `rtspclientsink rtsp://localhost:8554/realtime`.

I tried using sync=false as a parameter, but that did not resolve the issue.

Could someone provide some insight into why both outputs are delayed and how to achieve real-time playback with one while maintaining a delay on the other? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The "rtspclientsink" has an element property "latency" which defaults to 2000ms. Try setting it to 0.

```
... ! rtspclientsink latency=0 location=...
```

Your using the "v4l2h264enc" element which I don't have, but if it's similar to the "x264enc" element it may have a property to tune the encoding performance.

The "x264enc" element has property "tune" which defaults to "none". Using "zerolatency" reduces latency.

```
... ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! ...
```

You can check what properties "v4l2h264enc" has using

```
gst-inspect-1.0 v4l2h264enc
```